# What I am doing wrong with below "Set" property?

Tags: c#

I was trying to create simple event and below is the block of code but its not working. When I try to debug, as soon as we create Point object it is throwing "StackOverFlowException" at "Set" property(even before we assign the value p.x=10). What I am doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace Workshop
{

    public class Point
    {
        public int x
        {
            get { return x; }
            set
            {
                x = value;
                onPointeChanged();
            }
        }

        public int y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set
            {
                y = value;
                onPointeChanged();
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler pointchanged;

        private void onPointeChanged()
        {
            if (pointchanged != null)
                pointchanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Point p = new Point();
            p.pointchanged += HandleEvent;
            p.x = 10;
        }

        public static void HandleEvent(object obj, EventArgs sender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Raised");
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Properties should always start with uppercase-characters whereas fields should start with `_` or lowercase. I'm missing the backing-fields of these properties. [Naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) are very important, for example to avoid these bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the `set` method indefinitelly until you run out of stack memory. What you're doing with

```
x = value;
```

is you're calling the `x` property's setter, which in turn does `x = value`, so it calls itself, and so on, and so on for all eternity.

To fix this, introduce a field:

```
private int x;

public int X
{
    get => x;
    set
    {
         x = value;
         OnPointChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the proper way of creating properties with custom logic behind `get` and/or `set`. If you didn't have your `OnPointChanged()` logic you could just do

```
public int X { get; set; }
```

which would generate the following code for you under the hood:

```
private int x;
public int X { get => x; set => x = value; }
```

Comment: No, there's not. A Property is a wrapper for a field, so technically it's not even a variable. It's a method group. As I mentioned, even when you're "not creating another variable" the compiler is actually doing that for you behind the mask.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are assigning the property a value in its own setter:

```
public int x
{
    get { return x; }
    set
    {
        x = value; // <-- see you are assigning `value` to your `x` property.
        onPointeChanged();
    }
}
```

This will loop over and over again ad infinitum.  You need to create a backing field:

```
private int _myField;

public int BetterNameThanX
{
    get { return _myField; }
    set
    {
        _myField = value;
        onPointeChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to trigger onPointeChanged() without creating backing field. I just wanted to trigger event when value is set.

Comment: Not without getting into complicated cross-cutting concerns that monitor property changes across your app.  Not for beginners.

Comment: If possible please provide reference where they doing this.

Comment: I'm sorry but like I said it's a complicated topic and I'm not going to do your research for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined properties and you return every own property which causes recursivity on `get` and `set` scopes. Try to define private `attributes` and expose it by properties:

```
public class Point
{
    private int _x;
    public int x
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            onPointeChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _y;
    public int y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            onPointeChanged();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler pointchanged;

    private void onPointeChanged()
    {
        if (pointchanged != null)
            pointchanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```